# errorMessage is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, partial

How do I use errorMessage object from routes in a partial.I tried this

Route:-

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const Character = require("../models/character");

// All Character
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("characters/index");
});

// New Character
router.get("/new", (req, res) => {
  res.render("characters/new", { character: new Character() });
});

// Creat
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  const character = new Character({
    name: req.body.name,
  });
  character.save((err, newCharacter) => {
    if (err) {
      res.render("characters/new", {
        character: character,
        errorMessage: "Error Creating",
      });
    } else {
      // res.redirect(`characters/${newCharacter.id}`)
      res.redirect("characters");
    }
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

layout:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Test</title>
</head>
 <body>
   <%- include("../views/partials/header.ejs") %> 
   <%- include("../views/partials/errorMessage.ejs") %>
 <br />
 <%- body %>
 <br />
 </body>
 </html>
```

partial :-

```
<%= errorMessage %>
```

it gives me this error:-

```
ReferenceError: D:\Web_Development\LGS\layouts\layout.ejs:10
8| 

9|   <body>

 >> 10|     <%- include("../views/partials/header.ejs") %> <%-

11|     include("../views/partials/errorMessage.ejs") %>

12|     <br />

13|     <%- body %>


 D:\Web_Development\LGS\views\partials\errorMessage.ejs:1
 >> 1| <%= errorMessage %>

 2| 

 errorMessage is not defined
```

Comment: The partial assumes that all `res.render()` calls pass an `errorMessage` argument.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe should you try to include specifix variables :

```
<%- include("../views/partials/errorMessage.ejs", {errorMessage}) %>
```

Or just check the avaibality of your variable as it's in the main layout...

```
<% if (errorMessage !== undefined) { %>
      <%= errorMessage %>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. But I tried it and it gave me same error. Can you suggest anything else?

Comment: Yes stupid, but,.... does the error message if defined ?
You should wrap a condition to check if your variable is defined... I suppose it's this...

Answer (score 0):

You are passing data from sever to "characters/new.ejs" this file
and now in new.ejs file you have used layouts such as header and errorMessage by using <%- include() %> statement
and to pass data from new.ejs file to this layouts you need to provide second argument to <%- include() %> statement and object of data that you want to pass

> so in your example to pass errorMessage to
>   "../views/partials/errorMessage.ejs" you need to provide

```
<%- include("../views/partials/errorMessage.ejs", {errorMessage}) %>
```

then you can use this passed data to your layout like <%= errorMessage %>
if you want to pass more then one data you can do this

```
<%- include("../views/partials/errorMessage.ejs", {data1, data2, ...}) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this it might be helpful it worked for me !!!!!

<% if(locals.errorMessage != null) {%>

<%= errorMessage %>

<%}%>

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem... and I solved it by using this:
`<%= locals.errorMessage %>`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).